# iOS Sprite Kit how to make a projectile point at target in landscape orientation?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, rotation, geometry, sprite-kit

I have an icon within my sprite kit game that I intend to use as an animated projectile for when one character shoots another one. I'm trying to orient this projectile to point at the target.

[image]

I'm rotating it by a base angle of pi/4.0 to point it straight to the right. then I want the arrow to rotate from this position and point at target.

The code below almost works, but to my eye, it always looks as if the projectile is off from the correct angle. If the angle is correct, the arrow will point in the direction of movement when the arrow is given an action to move to the target x,y coordinate.

**How can I correctly calculate the angle to fire projectile from one (x,y) point to another (x,y) point?**

**EDIT: The code below works now, just needed to do zeroCheckedY/zeroCheckedX.**

```
//correct for pointing in the bottom right corner    
    float baseRotation = M_PI/4.0;   
    float zeroCheckedY = destination.y - origin.y;
    float zeroCheckedX = destination.x - origin.x;
    SKAction* rotate = nil;
    if(zeroCheckedX != 0)
    {
//not sure if I'm calculating this angle correctly.
        float angle =  atanf(zeroCheckedY/zeroCheckedX);
        rotate =  [SKAction rotateByAngle:baseRotation + angle duration:0];
    }else
    {
        rotate =  [SKAction rotateByAngle:baseRotation duration:0];

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem: cannon must "track" a target.
In `CannonNode` I defined the following method:

```
- (void)catchTargetAtPoint:(CGPoint)target {
    CGPoint cannonPointOnScene = [self.scene convertPoint:self.position fromNode:self.parent];
    float angle = [CannonNode pointPairToBearingDegreesWithStartingPoint:cannonPointInScene endingPoint:target];
    if (self.zRotation < 0) {
        self.zRotation = self.zRotation + M_PI * 2;
    }
    if ((angle < self.maxAngle) && (angle> self.minAngle)) {
        [self runAction:[SKAction rotateToAngle:angle duration:1.0f]];
    }
}

+ (float)pointPairToBearingDegreesWithStartingPoint:(CGPoint)startingPoint endingPoint:(CGPoint) endingPoint {
    CGPoint originPoint = CGPointMake(endingPoint.x - startingPoint.x, endingPoint.y - startingPoint.y); // get origin point to origin by subtracting end from start
    float bearingRadians = atan2f(originPoint.y, originPoint.x); // get bearing in radians
    return bearingRadians;
}
```

`catchTargetAtPoint` must be called within `update` method of the scene.